# Genering IPod and Zune Compatible RSS Feeds for MP3's hosted on Amazon S3 Server

Tags: podcast

I have few MP3 recordings which are hosted on the Amazon S3 server. I want to expose those recordings (MP3 files) to the users as RSS feeds so that they can download them using their IPod (Itunes) or Zune.

All the MP3's are hosted on Amazon S3 server and I would also like to have a stat that which podcast is downloaded how many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically just a matter of building the RSS file and hosting it on an HTTP server.  Then you just give users the URL to that feed and they can subsribe in iTunes.  Here is a link to the iTunes RSS technical spec: [iTunes Podcast RSS Technical Spec](http://www.apple.com/itunes/whatson/podcasts/specs.html#rss)  There's also an example feed on that page to get you started.

The element that stores the actual location of the files is the `enclosure` element.  It has a URL attribute which needs to be set to the URL of the MP3.

Example: `<enclosure url="http://example.com/podcasts/everything AllAboutEverythingEpisode2.mp3" length="5650889" type="audio/mpeg"/>`

All your enclosure elements will just need to point to the proper place in Amazon S3.